# Format number in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to format number with decimal places to format without decimal places, example: 146.5 to 146500000. How can i achieve this in PHP?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by 100000?

Couldn't be that easy.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this:

1. Multiply the number by some power of 10
2. User `number_format` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)) to add the zeros, then use str_replace ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)) to remove the decimal point

Answer (score 0):

```
$formatted_number = preg_replace('/\./', '', sprintf('%06f', $number));
```

Comment: Really, regexp to replace a simple dot?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant 1465.00000 then you could use  floor($num);

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers can be tricksy, be sure to do any multiplication with an extended math library.  Check out [`bcmul()` from the BC Math Library](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) for more info.