# PHP Number format as Output

Tags: php, function, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format number in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722588/format-number-in-php)

I want my number format `12 char in length`, like if there is value `12` it should output     `000000000012`

Example: if value is `123.50` it should output `000000012350` No decimal (multiple of 100)

Any idea, which function will be used?

Thanks !

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: i already read above quest, but both are diff in terms of output required

Comment: simply works with `str_pad(number_format($order_total, 2, '', ''), 12, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
  echo str_pad(12, 12, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

You can also use [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)  or [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
  printf("%012s", 12);
```

Output

```
000000000012
```

Some Work Arounds

```
var_dump(formatOutput("12"));
var_dump(formatOutput("123.50"));
var_dump(formatOutput("123.378201"));


function formatOutput($no,$max = 15) {
    $no = str_pad("1", strlen(substr(strrchr($no, "."), 1)), "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT) * $no;
    if(strpos($no, "."))
        $no = str_replace(".", "", $no) . "0" ;
    return str_pad($no, $max, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Output

```
string '000000000000012' (length=15)
string '000000000001235' (length=15)
string '000001233782010' (length=15)
```

Comment: if i enter value as 123.50, it will output: `0000000123.5` can you tell me how to get `000000012350` ? tnx in advance

Comment: Hold on ... i would update in a moment

Comment: What if it is 123.378201 @Barmar

Comment: What do you want the result to be for that? Maybe you just need to use `str_replace` on the result to remove the "."?

Comment: guys, needs better solution to this as its payment gateway total amount to send..

Comment: i think, still there is an issue, for ex: `amount is 224`, it should output `000000022400` while at present, it gives: `000000000224` as result.. can you please correct it? tnx in advance

Comment: why should `224` return `000000022400` i don't see any decimal places convert 224 to decimal places with number_format and it would output what you want

Comment: the reason my payment merchant accepts that way only for 224 it should be `000000022400` if i pass `000000000224` - it counts it as `22.4` so all calculations goes wrong from thr

Comment: That makes it very easy ... multiply by `100` and pad it with zeros .. or use the function .. that should work iamtheladylegend

Comment: finally i found it working simply: str_pad(number_format($order_total, 2, '', ''), 12, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); thanks guys for your help n all support

Comment: Well done....  @iamtheladylegend

Comment: @Baba: thank you guys for your help n support :)

Comment: @iamtheladylegend. ... You are welcome anytime

Answer (score 2):

See `str_pad()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 1):

```
string str_pad ( string $input , int $pad_length [, string $pad_string = " " [, int $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT ]] )
```

This functions returns the input string padded on the left, the right, or both sides to the specified padding length. If the optional argument pad_string is not supplied, the input is padded with spaces, otherwise it is padded with characters from pad_string up to the limit.

```
input
```

The input string.

```
pad_length
```

If the value of pad_length is negative, less than, or equal to the length of the input string, no padding takes place.

```
pad_string
```

The pad_string may be truncated if the required number of padding characters can't be evenly divided by the pad_string's length.

```
pad_type
```

Optional argument pad_type can be STR_PAD_RIGHT, STR_PAD_LEFT, or STR_PAD_BOTH. If pad_type is not specified it is assumed to be STR_PAD_RIGHT.

Answer (score 1):

```
    sprintf();
```

Check php manual [sprintf() function in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Along with `printf()`can do the job. Check example 7 in the link above.